# Silhouette detection in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv

I am trying to detect the silhouette of a person in iOS using OpenCV 2.4.9. I am using the background subtraction using mixture of gaussians to achieve it. Ref : http://personal.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Personal/R.Bowden/publications/avbs01/avbs01.pdf and  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog

Here is my code snippet ;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!"      message:@"Welcome to OpenCV" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Continue" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    //[alert show];

    self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc] initWithParentView:imageView]; // Sets up the camera
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront; // Back-Front  Camera
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset352x288;
    self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 30; // FPS
    self.videoCamera.delegate = self;
    //self.videoCamera.grayscale = NO; 
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)processImage:(Mat&)image
{
    cvtColor( image, image, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    // Canny edge detector ...
    Canny(image, image, 100, 300); // Adjust thresholds 
    threshold(image, image, 100, 255, THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    // find contours
    findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_CCOMP, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,     cv::Point(0,0));

    int idx = 0;
    for (; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0] )
    {
        drawContours( image, contours, idx, 255, 1, 4, hierarchy ); 
    }
    bitwise_not(image, image);

    Ptr<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2> B = Algorithm::create<BackgroundSubtractorMOG2>("BackgroundSubtractor.MOG2");

    B->setDetectShadows(false);
    B->setNMixtures(3);

    B->createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(image,fore);
    B->apply(image,fore);
    B->getBackgroundImage(bg);
    erode(fore, fore, Mat());
    dilate(fore, fore, Mat());

    findContours(fore, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    drawContours(image, contours, -1, Scalar(0,255,0),2);
}
```

And I get a Thread7:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x0) at

```
B->setDetectShadows(false);
```

meaning my B is NULL.

I did some debugging and found that B gets initialized first and then set to NULL within OpenCV ;

```
inline
String::String(const char* s)
    : cstr_(0), len_(0)
{
    if (!s) return;
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    memcpy(allocate(len), s, len);
}


template<typename _Tp> inline
Ptr<_Tp> Algorithm::create(const String& name)
{
    return _create(name).dynamicCast<_Tp>();
}

template<typename T>
template<typename Y>
Ptr<Y> Ptr<T>::dynamicCast() const
{
    return Ptr<Y>(*this, dynamic_cast<Y*>(stored));
}
```

and then finally set to NULL !?

```
template<typename T>
void Ptr<T>::release()
{
    if (owner) owner->decRef();
    owner = NULL;
    stored = NULL;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong and/or how can this be corrected ?

I have done this project in the past in C++ using Visual Studio and OpenCV 2.3 and I could just create an object of type BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 and just use setNMixtures and so on. But for some reason this class in iOS is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

[The doc on Algorithm::create](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=algorithm#algorithm-create) contains a note:

> **Note** This is important note about seemingly mysterious behavior of `Algorithm::create()` when it returns NULL while it should not. The reason is simple - `Algorithm::create()` resides in OpenCV's core module and the algorithms are implemented in other modules. If you create algorithms dynamically, C++ linker may decide to throw away the modules where the actual algorithms are implemented, since you do not call any functions from the modules. To avoid this problem, you need to call `initModule_<modulename>();` somewhere in the beginning of the program before Algorithm::create(). For example, call `initModule_nonfree()` in order to use SURF/SIFT, call `initModule_ml()` to use expectation maximization etc.

So I believe in your case you have to call `initModule_video()` before creating the algorithm.

Comment: Added initModule_video() before the implementation. However, it doesn't solve the issue.